# Check file existence with formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this requirement of creating hyperlink only if file exists at the location.
as each file name will be different fetched from cells after entering data.

`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(J10)),HYPERLINK(O6&J10&".jpg", "Bill Available"),"")`

I have this formula, which creates hyperlink as soon as i enter something in "J10" and creates hyperlink to path "O6" and file name "J10". Nut I dont want it to create hyperlink if file is not there... I'm thinking of using "AND" with "IF" but how to check file existence?

Comment: You can't check the file exists directly. You'd need to write some VBA to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with the help of a VBA User Defined Function.

1) Open the Visual Basic Editor and click `Insert -> Module`**
2) Paste the following code***:

```
Function FileExists(sPath As String)
    FileExists = Dir(sPath) <> ""
End Function
```

Then you can use `FileExists` in the same way as any other function. So, as you suggested:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(J10)),FileExists(O6&J10&".jpg")),HYPERLINK(O6&J10&".jpg", "Bill Available"),"")
```

Should work.

** In newer versions of Excel, with the Ribbon, you may have to enable the 'Developer' tab (`File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Check 'Developer'`)

*** This code lifted from [here](http://excel.tips.net/T007512_Checking_for_the_Existence_of_a_File.html), but with a typo corrected (`FileExists1` -> `FileExists`).