# auto calculation for formula that is defined through whether a file exists

Tags: excel, vba, formula

here is the formula:
=IF(doesfileexists($AT$3&$P16&$AS$3&$P16&".xls"),"CF✔","*")

the only problem is that if the file is deleted, it doesnt change. On the other hand, if i click on the formula to edit it and click enter, it then recalculates to the right value. i would like to automate this process of pressing enter
*note: My data calculation is set to automatic and works with other data entries. Maybe the fact that it includes a function(doesfileexists) changes something??

Thank you very mech to all.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/205222/1531971 and especially https://stackoverflow.com/q/1586169/1531971

Answer (score 0):

The below link explains the use of function "FileExists", can you give this a try.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36308613/8251387

Comment: Thats where i found the info. My problem is that my formula doesnt update

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the function Volatile so that it calculates at every Excel calculation: add `Application.Volatile=True`

But deleting a file from a folder will not of itself trigger an Excel calculation.

Comment: here is my function with the added 'application.volatile=true';               Len(LTrim(Dir(File_path))) > 0 Then    Doesfileexists = True    Else    Doesfileexists = False    End IfApplication.Volatile = TrueEnd Function

Comment: it prompts a compilation error saying it expected a function or variable